# I have a CGridview with a list of patients and I need a button url in the grid so that it prints the update page of the current record?

Tags: yii

I need to get the details of the patients in my `CGridview` when I click an icon in the grid it should print the details (which is in the update page) of the patients.

Already tried `window.print()` and `(.class).printPage()` but don't know how to implement those?

Comment: So you want an icon in your gridview that when clicked, opens the browser print window, for the update page of the patient record that was clicked?

Comment: Yes Eskimo. You got it right.

Answer (score 0):

In you `CGridView` call (probably in your admin view of your patient views), add an additional button like so:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{printbutton}{view}{update}{delete}',
    'buttons'=>array(
        'printbutton' => array(
            'label'=>'Print',
            'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/print_icon.png',
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("patient/printitem", array("id"=>$data->id))',
         ),
    ),
),
```

You will see that this:

- References an image (in this example stored in *image/print_icon.png*) to be used as the icon
- References a Controller/Action URL (in this example *patient/printitem*) and passes it the `id` of the patient record that was clicked

This Controller/Action must now select the patient record, and then render a view, something like:

```
public function actionPrintitem(){
    $model = Patient::model()->findByPk($_REQUEST['id']);
    $this->render("printitem",array(
        "model" => $model
    ));
}
```

Now, in this view (which you will have to create), simply put a `window.print();` to fire once the page has loaded, which will open the browser print window

Comment: Thanks eskimo I am checking it.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Eskimo it prints a blank page.

Comment: What is the content of your `printitem` view? You most likely will duplicate your `update` or `view` views

Comment: Its actually a bulk page contains data from different tables I already created a image url and url as you said I just modified the action to render to a new page called print which contains only the windows.print()

Comment: No, the new page you made must contain the content that you want to be printed, not just a `window.print();`